# Problem with building a code that solves sequence in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n ;
    double x, factorial=1;
    printf(" please enter n and x\n");
    scanf_s("%d %lf", &n, &x);
    double result =( x - 1), sum = (x-1);
    for (int i =1; i <=n; i++)
    {
        result = ((x-1)*(x-1));
        printf("%lf\n", result);
        factorial = ((2*i)*(2*i+1));
        printf("%lf\n", factorial);
        sum +=( result / (factorial * (i+1)));
        printf("%.2lf\n", sum);
        
    }

    //printf("%.2lf\n", sum);
}
```

hello everyone, I've got a task with creating a code that the user types in 'n' and 'x' and gets the sum to this sequence

When I run the code the sum stays the same
ignore the printf under sum factorial and result it's for testing.
is there a way to make this code better? and for everything to work fine?

Comment: Did you get any warnings or errors when compiling? `(x-1)(x-1)` and `(2*i)(2*i+1)` are not valid C.

Comment: `result = ((x-1)(x-1));` ==> `result = ((x-1) * (x-1));`  Rinse, repeat everywhere you make this, or similar, mistakes.

Comment: "When I run the code" That is impossible with the shown code, because the shown code cannot be compiled. If you do not take care with making a correct [mre] then you will get answers which fix the compiler errors instead of dicussing your actual problem. And then you will have to ask a new separate question, which asks your actual problem with a correct MRE, because chaging a question so that existing answers are not valid anymore is considered a "moving target question" and not appreciated on StackOverflow.

Comment: Aaaaand - it has happened. So please, take the [tour], read [ask], read [mre]. Then create a new question and ask about the actual problem you have, with a MRE to demonstrate what you want to discuss.

Comment: "the sum stays the same" No it doesn't. You are mistaken. You are not printing which number means what. Also please no NOT use `void main()` and `scanf_s`. These are Windows-specific things that are not supported by mainstream compilers and operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

its not `void main()` it should be `int main()`

and you have to write out the "*" in between brackets when you want to perform multiplication

```
result = ((x-1)*(x-1));
factorial = ((2*i)*(2*i+1));
```

I think this should fix your problems

The full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n ;
    double x, factorial=1;
    printf(" please enter n and x\n");
    scanf_s("%d %lf", &n, &x);
    double result =( x - 1), sum = (x-1);
    for (int i =1; i <=n; i++)
    {
        result = ((x-1)*(x-1));
        printf("%lf\n", result);
        factorial = ((2*i)*(2*i+1));
        printf("%lf\n", factorial);
        sum +=( result / (factorial * (i+1)));
        printf("%.2lf\n", sum);

    }

    printf("%.2lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please be more careful with fixing things OPs is not actually asking about. Only solving compiler errors is not really an answer to the question OP wanted to ask. You can tell by the fact that OP describes runtime behaviour of code while the shown code is not compileable. OP is likely to delete the question (which will mean the repuation you gained here is lost) or to change the question away from what you answered (which makes your answer seem wrong and might attract downvotes; you might still have a net gain of reputation though.....).

Comment: The code didn't show that I put * between brackets so I edited it out... I'll point out that my real actual problem isn't compiling it, it's getting a faulty sum at ``` sum +=( result / (factorial * (i+1))); ```

Comment: @Sapka `getting a faulty sum` You didn't say what the "*right*" sum was supposed to be.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65033774/edit) your question and 1) explain what the code is trying to do, 2) post real, compilable code, and 3) tell what the inputs are, what the expected result is, and what you are getting, instead.

Comment: @dxiv I can't upload image of the compiler sadly so I can't show you

Comment: @Sapka All that I was asking for is pure text. Please don't (try to) post unnecessary pictures.